# How to do Smart Tracking on Mavic 3 Enterprise?

Tags: dji, smartphone-app

I just got a DJI Mavic 3 Enterprise Multispectral (M3M) for work and am learning how to use it.

The hardware itself is great, but I’m having lots of troubles with the DJI Pilot 2 app on the Enterprise remote. The app on my remote is just so different then the app shown on the official DJI YouTube instructional videos. In those videos, they are constantly referencing "camera mode" versus "zoom mode," but I cannot figure out what they’re referring to on the current app.

In particular, I have been referencing [this very short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pILWBM1jIyk) where they set the camera to zoom mode, and use it for Smart Tracking of an object. I cannot find the zoom mode, when I try to draw a square on normal, sport, or tri-pod mode absolutely nothing happens...

How do you do Smart Tracking on the DJI Pilot 2 app of a Mavic 3 Enterprise remote?